# XSLT 1.0 build hierarchy from parent-child relationship

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following flat xml structure.

```
<customUI >
  <elements>
    <tab id="1" parent="0"/>
    <tab id="-1" parent="0"/>
    <group id="-2"  parent="-1"/>
    <group id="2"  parent="1"/>
    <group id="11"  parent="1"/>
    <menu id="-27"  parent="-26"/>
    <menu id="-24" parent="-4"/>
    <menu id="-18" parent="-4"/>
    <menu id="-11"  parent="-9"/>
    <menu id="-10" parent="-9"/>
    <menu id="-3"  parent="-2"/>
    <menu id="3"  parent="2"/>
    <menu id="10" parent="65"/>
    <menu id="12"  parent="11"/>
    <menu id="16"  parent="11"/>
    <menu id="18" parent="11"/>
    <menu id="25" parent="11" />
    <menu id="29" parent="11"/>
    <menu id="46" parent="11"/>
    <menu id="74" parent="-3"/>
    <menu id="85" parent="11"/>
    <menu id="89" parent="2"/>
    <menu id="95" parent="2"/>
    <menu id="104"  parent="2"/>
    <button id="-28"  parent="-2"/>
    <button id="-25" parent="-24"/>
    <button id="-12" parent="-11"/>
    <button id="32" parent="29"/>
    <button id="26" parent="25"/>
    <button id="41" parent="18"/>
    <button id="66" parent="46"/>
    <button id="82"  parent="74"/>
    <button id="86" parent="46"/>
    <button id="87"  parent="89"/>
    <button id="90"  parent="89"/>
    <button id="99"  parent="89"/>
    <button id="58"  parent="16"/>
    <button id="42" parent="18"/>
    <button id="47"  parent="46"/>
    <button id="48"  parent="46"/>
    <button id="33" parent="29"/>
    <!-- The list continues -->
  </elements>
</customUI>
```

What I would like to do is to build a hierarchy using the relationship between the 'id' value and 'parent' value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tab">
    <xsl:variable name="controllerId" select="@id" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//*[@parent = $controllerId]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="group" name="group">
    <xsl:variable name="controllerId" select="@id" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="//*[@parent = $controllerId]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="menu" name="menu">
    <xsl:variable name="controllerId" select="@id" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="//*[@parent = $controllerId]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I have tried until now but it does not work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the output you are expecting in this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit crude, but it should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="elements">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:if test="not(../*[@id=current()/@parent])">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="elements/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[@parent = current()/@id]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The `elements` template copies it, but for each element within it, it only applies templates if there is no other sibling who's parent is this one; i.e. if your data represents a complete hierarchy, it'll probably only be the root.

The second template applies to anything in an elements template, and copies as-is, then also includes any other elements who's parent is the current one, recursively.

An alternative using keys that might be faster, but would have problems if there's more than one `elements` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="elemsById" match="elements/*" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="elemsByParent" match="elements/*" use="@parent"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="elements">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(key('elemsById',@parent))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="elements/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elemsByParent',@id)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am out of words... How is it even possible to come with a solution so fast... And most amazing it seems that it works.

Comment: Got lucky to be honest. I did something very similar recently, it wasn't significantly different.

Comment: By the way, since I am beginner can you please recommend me some sources from where I can learn XSLT in a more structured way because right now I am in the stage where is more trial and error and this unfortunately is time consuming.

Comment: Personally I found it a lot easier to just practice, practice, practice. There are a number of websites that have a 'sandbox' for trial & error that make it a lot less time consuming, such as xsltransform.net where you actually see the results as you're typing. This question has been asked before, but it's generally considered off-topic for SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271/what-is-a-good-resource-for-learning-xsl)

Comment: @Andy The most "structured" way to learn XSLT and XPath is still Michael Kay's book on those two topics. Although Michael Kay clearly says it's not meant to be an introduction to XSLT, it's well-written and very useful.